# Is there a keyboard shortcut or app to *SWITCH* displays content?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, display, window-manager

Is there a free app or shortcut that I can switch my  Mac's windows content from one monitor to the other monitor (assuming only two monitors) via the keyboard or app?

I know there is a way to move window to the next screen, but it's not enough for me.

If I have Chrome open in monitor 1 and Zoom in monitor 2 - and I want to switch between them - is it possible?

Comment: To understand your request - you want to be able to swap what's on the two monitors? - I.e. if you have windows A and B on monitor 1, and windows C and D on monitor 2, you want to be able to press a key, and now C+D is shown on monitor 1, and A+B is shown on monitor 2?

Comment: @jksoegaard - exactly! :)

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you're trying to do? Ultimately, it sounds like you want to swap the displays used by two apps, rather than everything in each display.

Answer (score -2):

Not exactly a shortcut, but if you go to "Displays" and then go to "Arrangement", there is a small white rectangle. If you move it, you can change the content of your displays. [image: Pointing to the red rectangle]